# why was my profile transferred here from stack overflow?

Tags: support

I have been using Stack Overflow for some time as I undertake a massive programming  project in various languages that are new to me. It has been enormously helpful. I provided some user information when asked.

When I got onto Math Exchange I was asked whether I wanted my profile transferred and said no.  But the user information was transferred.

The user information is perfectly true, but not what I would have put on the Math Exchange site. Can I do something about this?

Comment: Can you edit your math.stackexchange profile? If so, that would be a good way.

Comment: Was it an immediate profile transfer (e.g. as soon as you logged in, the data was there), or was it delayed?  I know that saving a user profile on a different stack exchange site can copy data to all of them...

Comment: @robjohn -- I'll try to edit it; thanks for the tip.

Comment: @anorton -- darned if I can remember.  In fact, I may never have known.

Comment: @BettyMock That's ok.  I hadn't looked at your profile (until now) to realize that you hadn't transferred membership within the past day or so... `:o`

Comment: Well, I can't edit it on math exchange.  I removed it from Stack Exchange, but it is still here on math exchange.  Any other suggestions?